# Can't get Office365 Message Trace log

Tags: c#, office365

I am using code from this link https://github.com/microsoft/o365rwsclient to get message trace log from Office365.
Everything was working fine until the last 2 weeks, I always get the error

> One or more errors occurred.:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
> at Microsoft.Office365.ReportingWebServiceClient.ReportProvider.GetAsyncResult[T](Task`1 asyncFunction) in D:\LapTrinh\LogOffice365\ToolLogO365\o365rwsclient-master\ReportProvider.cs:line 48
> at Microsoft.Office365.ReportingWebServiceClient.ReportProvider.GetResponseContent(String serviceFullUrl) in D:\LapTrinh\LogOffice365\ToolLogO365\o365rwsclient-master\ReportProvider.cs:line 111
> One or more errors occurred.:   at Microsoft.Office365.ReportingWebServiceClient.ReportProvider.GetResponseContent(String serviceFullUrl) in D:\LapTrinh\LogOffice365\ToolLogO365\o365rwsclient-master\ReportProvider.cs:line 132
> at Microsoft.Office365.ReportingWebServiceClient.ReportProvider.GetResponseXml(Type reportType, QueryFilter filter) in D:\LapTrinh\LogOffice365\ToolLogO365\o365rwsclient-master\ReportProvider.cs:line 159

Specifically, the code still runs normally for 2-3 minutes, then it will fail and send the error message as above.

My command line example is https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTrace?$top=2000&$skiptoken=2000&$filter=(StartDate eq datetime'2021-10-01T00: 57:35') and (EndDate eq datetime'2021-10-01T01:01:11')

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

After testing, it seems that Office365 has changed the way to query for Message Trace.
It became like this

> https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTrace?$top=2000&$skiptoken=2000&$filter=(StartDate eq StartDate ') and (EndDate eq datetime'EndDate')

instead of

> https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTrace?$top=2000&$skiptoken=2000&$filter=StartDate eq 'StartDate' and EndDate eq datetime'EndDate'

I fixed it and it works fine.
Thanks for care.